# Why both corr(x, y) and corr(a, b) can be larger than corr([x, a], [y, b])?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices, vectors, python

Here, corr(**x**, **y**) means the cosine similarity, and [**x**, **a**] means the concatenation of two vectors.

I thought it should always hold that corr(**x**, **y**) $\ll$ corr([**x**, **a**], [**y**, **b**])  $\ll$ corr(**a**, **b**), but oneday, I found it was wrong when I computed using real datasets, and the relation as shown in the question title could hold in some situtation.

My question: can we prove in which situtation the title  holds, and some clear numerical simulations are also welcome.

In python3.7, I find a simulation which however cannot give me enough intuitive hints:

```
np.random.seed(0)
yn = np.random.normal(loc=0.00028, scale=0.00098, size=1000).tolist()
yn_hat = np.random.normal(loc=0.00008, scale=0.000248, size=1000).tolist()
print(corr(yn, yn_hat)) #4.872580685041682

ye = np.random.normal(loc=0.00424, scale=0.031, size=1000).tolist()
ye_hat = np.random.normal(loc=0.0097, scale=0.0274, size=1000).tolist()
print(corr(ye, ye_hat)) #3.8225452426943805

print(corr(yn+ye, yn_hat+ye_hat)) #3.8216710106475364
#in python, the 'add' of two list is the concatenation not element-wise addition
```

Comment: See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson%27s_paradox#Correlation_between_variables).

Comment: @J.G. Seems mine is about vector concatenation